# How can I shorten the runtime of for loops and if statements in R while using igraph for forest fire simulations

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, simulation, igraph

I am simulating forest fires in R and have to use the igraph package. My code currently works but is extremely slow. I read through ways of vectorizing my for loops or using seq_along or putting conditionals outside my loops. I was unable to figure out how to use these solutions in my specific code. As for the description of my code: I am simulating forest fires where I loop through 21 different percentages representing the likelihood of a blank vertex becoming a tree (0 through 1 by .05 intervals). In each of these loops I am running 100 full forest fires. Each forest fire is comprised of 50 time steps. In each time step, I check which vertices of my igraph need to be changed to empty, tree, and fire. For the specific problem I am working on, I am tracking the largest number of trees on fire during each forest fire so that I can later generate a graph of the average maximum fire for the 21 different percentages. Any tips on how to speed up this code would be much appreciated.

```
OG <- graph.lattice(c(30,30))
V(OG)$color <- "black"
total.burning.tree.max <- matrix(nrow = 21, ncol = 100)
for (p in seq(0, 1, .05)) {

for (x in 1:100) {
  fire.start <- sample(900, 1)
  tree.start <- sample(900, (900*.7))
  G <- OG
  V(G)$color[tree.start] <- "green"
  V(G)$color[fire.start] <- "red"
  current.burning.tree.max <- 1
  H <- G

  for (h in 1:50) {
    if (length(V(G)[color == "red"]) > current.burning.tree.max) {
      current.burning.tree.max <- length(V(G)[color == "red"])
    }
    for (i in 1:length(V(G)[color == "black"])) {
      if (runif(1) <= p) {
        V(H)$color[V(G)[color == "black"][i]] <- "green"
      }
    }
    if (length(V(G)[color == "red"]) > 0) {
      for (d in 1:length(V(G)[color == "red"])) {      
        V(H)$color[V(G)[color == "red"][d]] <- "black"
        potential.fires <- neighbors(G, V(G)[color == "red"][d])
        for (z in 1:length(potential.fires)) {
          if (V(G)$color[potential.fires[z]] == "green") {
            V(H)$color[potential.fires[z]] <- "red"
          }  
        }
      }
    }   
    G <- H
  }
  total.burning.tree.max[(p*20), x] <- current.burning.tree.max
  print(current.burning.tree.max) 
 }
}

burn.numbers <- c()
for (c in 1:21) {
  burn.numbers[c] <- average(total.burning.tree.max[c, ])
}
plot(burn.graph, type = "l")
```

Comment: I like this kind of exersices. You do have an awfull lot of nested loops, and deep inside you run `neighbours()` on a per-subset basis. You could probably omit the loops and have igraph work on groups of neighbors directly. Start by running some benchmarks by checking where your code is slow on your machine so you can concentrate your efforts on the right places. Start wher things are slowest. I'll attack this problem out of pure inspiration later next week when I have a free moment. I'm very optimistic that it can be accelerated quite significantly. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure about `V(H)$color[V(G)[color == "black"][i]] <- "green"`? Do you really wanna regrow black trees to green?

Answer (score 1):

**General notes on optimising your code:**

First of all, your code is full of nested loops where each simulation loops over nodes in `igraph` to change values. This is a bad idea, since `igraph` is quicker.

Consider for example this loop over all nodes of a given colour like you do:

```
for (i in 1:length(V(G)[color == "red"])) {
  V(H)$color[V(G)[color == "red"][i]] <- "black"
}
```

It would be better to store the subset of nodes, and use it to make changes all at once:

```
V(G)[ V(G)$color=="red" ] <- "black"
```

Note also that you need not place `runif(1, p)` inside a loop, but you can perform any number of probability comparisons if you let `runif()` output a vector like so:
runif(sum( V(G)$color=="red" ), 0, 1) <= p

Consider summarising boolean values when you don't need the actual value of a variable or `igraph` node attribute:

```
sum(V(G)$color=="red") == length( V(G)$color[ V(G)$color  =="red" ] )
```

In your example, as often when running simulations in general or in `igraph` in particular, computation speed depends on dynamics within the simulation. My script below, for example, executes much quicker for time-steps with few trees on fire. The function `adjacent_vertices()` is an obvious time-bandit here when it is instructed to return `mode="total"`. Yet, that function should be quicker than you looping around on your own.

When you look for iterations that consume a lot of time, you'd find that your script suffers a lot from checking neighbours of burning trees with burning neighbours.

**Introducing new behaviours to facilitate optimisation:**

My optimizing solution is to introduce a new colour: "orange", for fires that have already been spread. Since all trees with burning neighbours catch fire during each time-step, the simulation needs not check for neighbours of trees that cought fire before the previous time-step. This significantly reduces the number of neighbour-tests performed by `adjacent_vertices()`, a function that would run 20*100*50*270 or so times on `p=.05`. That's a million neighbour-checks right there! If we don't need to check for neighbours of yellow trees that already have all their neighbours alit, we save a lot of CPU cycles.

[image]

I hope I've provided some good general pointers. Next to your script above, the below script, I hope, can serve for pedagogical purposes.

In the script below, I've changed the way of storing simulation data, as well as a function in the simulation that I might have miss-understood. `p` below now states the probability that burning trees are put out each time-step, while neighbours of burning trees are sure to catch fire in the next time-step (as they were in your simulation).

Each level of `p` plots an example graph.

Note also that the line that sets new trees on fire can be ever so slightly optimised by removing the `runif()` that allows you to change values for a separate probability of neighbouring trees to catch fire.

```
tree_fires <-  potential_fires[  runif(length(potential_fires), 0, 1) <= FIRE_PROBABILITY  ]
```

As always in optimising. Spend your efforts where they count! Removing the `runif()` for `tree_fires` probably saves you only around a millionth of the time compared to moving to orange trees to ease the work of `adjacent_vertices()`.

**A note on your approach:**

I've done similar simulations of decease-spreading in social networks. It matters a lot where you put the initial fire. The maximum number of trees on fire in one iteration is capped a lot by the walls of your forest. This would result in significantly higher variation of your measurement within each level assumed by `p`. I very much suggest that you move to a model which places the initial fire in the middle of your forest. I've included configuration variables for this.

**Sugestion summary:**

```
library("igraph")
# Configurations
PROB_LEVELS <- 20            # How many probability levels?
FOREEST_SIMULATIONS <- 100   # How many simulations shouls occur for each probability level?
TIMESTEPS <- 50              # How many iterations shouls fires spread for in each simulation?
FIRE_PROBABILITY <- 1        # How likely is it that an adjacent tree will catch fire? (Lower values decrease speed of fire spreading)
FIXED_STARTING_POINT <- TRUE # Should the fire begin at the same place always?
PLAYGROUND <- 30             # The size of the forest (higher values decrease likelyhood of hiting foret-walls)
FOREST_DENSITY <- .7         # The percentage of nodes that are trees in an unburnt forest. (higher values facilitates spread of fire)

# 900 trees
OG <- graph.lattice(c(PLAYGROUND, PLAYGROUND))
V(OG)$color <- "gray"
# Store simulation results in a list instead.
stat <- lapply(1:PROB_LEVELS, function(x) rep(NA,FOREEST_SIMULATIONS))

plotforest <- function(graph){plot(graph, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=5, layout=layout_on_grid(graph) )}

# Make dimulations using these probabilities
for (p in 1:PROB_LEVELS/PROB_LEVELS) {
  cat("p =",p)

  for (x in 1:FOREEST_SIMULATIONS) {
    # Each iteration have different random configurations of forests with a fixed tree-density
    G <- OG
    V(G)$color[ sample(PLAYGROUND^2, (PLAYGROUND^2 * FOREST_DENSITY )) ] <- "green"
    # Firees could start at random tree or in the "middle"
    if(FIXED_STARTING_POINT){
      V(G)$color[ round(PLAYGROUND^2/2)-(PLAYGROUND/2) ] <- "red" }
    else{
      V(G)$color[ sample(PLAYGROUND^2, 1) ] <- "red" }


    # Collect simulation data over time-steps during which the fire spreads
    burning_tree_max <- 1
    for(h in 1:TIMESTEPS){
      # Put out trees that are on fire using probability `p`
      # This replaces your loop for (i in 1:length(V(G)[color == "red"])) {}
      trees_on_fire <- V(G)[ V(G)$color=="red" ] # make this subset only once per iteration. Store it. You could use %in% c('red','orange' )
      if(length(trees_on_fire) == 0){break;print(h)} # Abort time-steps if there are no more contageous fires.
      V(G)$color[ trees_on_fire[ runif(length(trees_on_fire), 0, 1) <= p ] ] <- "black"

      # Set neighboring trees of burning trees on fire (only green trees can catch fire)
      # This replaces your nested loop staring with for (d in 1:length(V(G)[color == "red"])) { }
      last_egnited <-  V(G)$color=="red"
      potential_fires <- adjacent_vertices(G, last_egnited, mode="total")
      potential_fires <- unique(unlist(potential_fires))
      potential_fires
      tree_fires <-  potential_fires[  runif(length(potential_fires), 0, 1) <= FIRE_PROBABILITY  ]
      # Store last time-step's burning trees as orange, and egnite new neighbors.
      V(G)$color[last_egnited] <- "orange"
      V(G)$color[tree_fires][V(G)$color[tree_fires] == "green"] <- "red" # Set all green subsetted neighbors of flaming treas on fire at once
      # No orange tree can have a green neighbour!

      # Track maximum number of trees on fire.
      burning_tree_max <- max(burning_tree_max, sum(V(G)$color=="red") )
    }

    # store simulation results as sum of currently burning trees
    stat[[p*PROB_LEVELS]][x] <- burning_tree_max

  }
  cat(": averaging", round(mean(stat[[p*PROB_LEVELS]], na.rm=T),1), "trees.", fill=T)
  plotforest(G)

}


# Plot the simulation results
plot(sapply(stat, function(x) mean(x)), type="l",
     ylab="Maximum number of trees on fire", xlab=NA,
     main="Snapshot of fires during a simulation",
     sub="50 time-cycles ona 30x30 sized forest ")
```